# Mavericks: MS Word crashing on documents with comments

Tags: ms-office, macos, crash

In short, Word crashes silently upon opening certain documents.  The problem seems to be with documents that include Comments.  I have tested by using WinWord to remove the comments from a file that crashed.  After removing the comments, Word opens just fine.

Furthermore, when creating new comments in a fresh document, Word crashes.

I have tried all

- reinstalled Word 14.3.8
- deleting all caches (font and otherwise) using Onyx
- Installing latest Java
- disabling MS Error Reporting

all of which didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Changing preferred language to English (as explained here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115387) worked for me!